How to enable OTP SMS Autofill on Keyboard in Xamarin iOS?
I am trying to implement the OTP SMS autofill feature in my Xamarin iOS application. Specifically, I want the OTP code to appear directly on the keyboard suggestion bar when an SMS containing the code is received. However, I am having trouble getting this feature to work despite following the available documentation and examples. The OTP code does not appear on the keyboard as expected.
I have tried to implement the OTP SMS autofill feature in my Xamarin iOS application by following various tutorials and the official documentation. Specifically, I used the following code to enable the OTP autofill:
// Renderer class for custom OTP entry control specific to iOS

  public class GdOtpEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(12, 0) && Control != null)
            {
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Custom entry control class for OTP input
public class GdOtpEntry : Entry
{
    public GdOtpEntry()
    {
        IsVisible = true;
        BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
        FontSize = 10;
        WidthRequest = 40;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        TextColor = Color.Black;
    }
}

// Page class where the custom OTP entry control is used
private GdOtpEntry _otpEntry;
public AuthenticationBottomPage(List<object> val = null)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        _otpEntry = new GdOtpEntry();
        UpdateiOSEntries(_otpEntry);
    }
    else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(this, "UpdateOtp", (sender, receivedOtp) =>
        {
            _otp = receivedOtp;
            UpdateEntries(_otp);
        });
    }
    Init(val);
}

// Method to update the OTP entries on iOS
private async void UpdateiOSEntries(GdOtpEntry otpEntry)
{
    await GdApp.Instance.UiManager.ShowLoadingAsync();
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(otpEntry.Text) && otpEntry.Text.Length >= 4)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            _entryFirstRect.Text = otpEntry.Text[0].ToString();
            _entrySecRect.Text = otpEntry.Text[1].ToString();
            _entryThirdtRect.Text = otpEntry.Text[2].ToString();
            _entryFourtRect.Text = otpEntry.Text[3].ToString();
            await GdApp.Instance.UiManager.HideLoadingAsync();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        await GdApp.Instance.UiManager.HideLoadingAsync();
    }
} 

I need to use the OTP SMS autofill feature introduced in iOS 12 in my cross-platform Xamarin application. Is there anything specific I need to do in Xcode or permissions that I need to add to the entitlements.plist file? I have successfully implemented this feature on Android, but I am struggling with getting the OTP to appear in the QuickType bar on iOS. Could someone please assist me with implementing this in Xamarin?
